# Matlab plot3 movie where the colour of each point varies depending on arbitrary vector

Tags: matlab, plot, colors, 3d, movie

I have a set of data arrays that are nx6, where the 1st 3 columns are the x, y, z coordinates of a trajectory and n varies. I have written a script in matlab that allows me to plot each point in succession and then make it into a movie, here is the code:

```
% attemt to make a movie! 
test = cou{7}(:,1:3) % data arrays are stored in larger cell arrays
numPoints = length(test(:,1))
x = test(:,1)
y = test(:,2)
z = test(:,3)
h = figure(1)
set(h,'Position',[100 678 560 420]) 

for j=1:numPoints
   plot3(test(1:j,1), test(1:j,2),test(1:j,3),'kd-')
   grid('on')
   xlim([min(x), max(x)])
   ylim([min(y), max(y)])
   zlim([min(z), max(z)])

   M(j) = getframe(h);
end

movie(M,1,30)
movie2avi(M,'testMovie2.avi')
```

This works great and I get a movie in .avi format. I get diamonds where each < x,y,z > coordinate is and the line that connects to the next point.

However, I need to add different colours depending on the 5th column in the nx6 matrix. In the 5th column there are numbers from 0-8, each number needs a specific colour, so that each new data point is plotted with a colour that is unique to the number in this column (0 is red, 1 is blue etc..).

From everything that I have read online it seems that I have to close one colour or split up the points into:

```
plot3(x1,y1,z1,s1,x2,y2,z2,s2, ...)
```

where x1,y1,z1,s1 would specify the first coordinate with s defining the colour, marker and line, x2,y2,z2,s2 the second point and its specifications etc..

Preferably, I would be able to define some sort of matrix S for the colour specification so that I could add it in to the plot like:

```
  plot3(x(1:j),y(1:j),z(1:j),S(1:j))
```

All of the related posts I have seen so far have been asking about/answered with a different 3D plot type. The the points in the trajectory jump all over. So I really need this plot type to be able to make the movie!

Cheers, 
Risa

P.S. I realize its not the most efficient code, and that the way I have it written now I can get rid of the test array. Ive been working on it most of the afternoon and its evolved into this. I just want to get it working then I will edit it for efficiency!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution could be:

- to define a matrix of colour indeces: since you need 9 colours it should be a (9 x 3) matrix
- to use the value stored in the 5th column of your data to select the color in the color matrix (i. e. to select the row, of the colour matrix)
- to set the selected colour to each line joining two points by specifying the parameter '`color`' in the `plot3` function call
- you can also use the selected color to fill the point markers by setting the `markerfacecolor`parameter

To do this you have to modify the indexing of the "test" data in your loop; actually, as it is now, every each iteration you are plotting all points from `1 to j` while you should plot them from `j to j+1`.

Because of this modification, you should also add `hold on`.

You can find the proposed updating in the code below.

**NOTICE:**

I had to comment the first part of your code and add some instructions to generate the test data.

**MORE IMPORTANT**

I've got a warning executing the last row of your code, about the compression factor and the codec.

```
Warning: Cannot locate Indeo5 compressor, using 'None' as the
compression type.
```

I've got this warning both when I run you original code and when I run the one with the updating, therefore it should be not depending on the modification I've made.

```
% attemt to make a movie! 
% test = cou{7}(:,1:3) % data arrays are stored in larger cell arrays
% numPoints = length(test(:,1))
% x = test(:,1)
% y = test(:,2)
% z = test(:,3)
% 
% Definition of example X, Y, Z points
% 
t=0:.3:2*pi;
x=cos(t);
y=sin(t);
z=(x.*y);
test=[x' y' z'];
numPoints = length(test)
% 
% Definition of color indeces
% 
test(:,5)=randi(9,numPoints,1);

h = figure(1)
set(h,'Position',[100 678 560 420]) 
% 
% Definiton of the set of colors
% 
line_col=[...
   0 0 1
   0 1 0
   0 1 1
   1 0 0
   1 0 1
   1 .1 .3
   .5 .5 .5
   .3 1 .3
   .7 .3 .9]

for j=1:numPoints-1
%
% Original plot instruction
% 
% % % plot3(test(1:j,1), test(1:j,2),test(1:j,3),'kd-')
% 
%    Updated plot instruction:
%       remove "k" color specification
%       specified 'color' and 'markerfacecolor' parameters
%       modified the indexig of the "test" dataset
% 
  a=plot3(test(j:j+1,1), test(j:j+1,2),test(j:j+1,3),'d-','color', ...
  line_col(test(j,5)+1,:),'markerfacecolor',line_col(test(j,5)+1,:), ...
  'linewidth',2)
   grid('on')
   xlim([min(x), max(x)])
   ylim([min(y), max(y)])
   zlim([min(z), max(z)])
% 
%    Addded "hold on" instruction, needed following the modification of the
%    indexing (see comment above)
% 
   hold on
   M(j) = getframe(h);
end

movie(M,1,30)
movie2avi(M,'testMovie2.avi')
```

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: This looks like exactly what I need! Thank you! As to the warning, on my work computer I have R2013a installed, it was not giving me this error when I ran the code. Could that be the reason?

Comment: I'm using R2012, so this could be be the reason of the warning. Notice, I've updated the line of code with `plot3` instruction: in order to catch the case of you have `0` as colour index, the colour specification in `plot3` should be `line_col(test(j,5)+1,:)` that is you have to `add 1` to the value of `test(j,5)`. Sorry about that

Comment: Yeah, I was able to get it to work last night. Personally I feel the documentation in Matlab needs to be updated. I used `help plot3` in the Matlab command line and it states **Various line types, plot symbols and colors may be obtained with
    plot3(X,Y,Z,s) where s is a 1, 2 or 3 character string made from
    the characters listed under the PLOT command.
  
    plot3(x1,y1,z1,s1,x2,y2,z2,s2,x3,y3,z3,s3,...) combines the plots
    defined by the (x,y,z,s) fourtuples, where the x's, y's and z's are
    vectors or matrices and the s's are strings.** but doesn't mention the 'colour' command!